# How to make LaTeX left column English and the right Chinese?

Tags: packages

So how to solve that two problems?
I want to make a bilingual book. And mainly in English, but I need add translation for English in the right column.
   All I can imagine is that every page is divided into two column. I finish the first page's left column, then finish the second page's left column, .... When the English part is over. I begin to write Chinese in the first page's right column, the second page's right column...
   Also every English paragraph should correspond to every Chinese paragraph. So maybe there are gaps among Chinese paragraphs.
  So how to solve that two problems?

Comment: Welcome! Are you aware of the `paracol` package? https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol

Comment: The other major option for this is the `reledpar` package https://ctan.org/pkg/reledpar

Comment: Perhaps one can translate paragraph by paragraph, and use the Tufte layout? http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf